# Running out of memory when making multiple Exchange Online V2 module connect calls in a process

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

We are trying to migrate to Exchange Online V2 module(EXO V2) from EXO V1. However, when we connect using the Connect-ExchangeOnline cmdlet, we observe the memory utilization goes to around ~200MB for the process.

We do this from C# code. However, doing the same from powershell.exe also gives us similar observation.

Post connect, we call the Disconnect-ExchangeOnline. We were under the impression calling the Disconnect-ExchangeOnline cmdlet should release the resources\memory. However, we don't see this happening. The memory utilization does not change.

Same connection establishing in V1 does not consume so much memory. So this used to work for us when we were using V1.

For our solution we need to make continuous calls to O365 for different tenants.  Our observation has been over a period of time this memory utilization keeps adding up and we end up running out of memory.

We tried to dispose the runspace, abort the thread etc. But unless the process is killed, the memory is not reclaimed.

We needed some pointers for this memory utilization. How can be make the EXO V2 connect call release the memory it has reserved?

Can someone please advice?

Comment: In case of PowerShell, you should avoid loading everything in memory by
*Properly* using the [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines). Meaning don't use parenthesis and don't assign object lists to a variable, instead stream each object inmidately to the next cmdlet.

Comment: @animesh-anand Do you still have this issue? I'm struggling with this as well. How did you solve this?

Comment: @RolandDeschain, we tried quite a few things(threads etc). Still we did not get enough memory free. Since we were using c#, we refactored our code to spawn a new process do the work and exit. This way the memory and resources were reclaimed by the OS. This is what we did to solve it for now.